# How do I play the new snapshot on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to play the new snapshot for Minecraft but I don't know how to do that for Bedrock Edition.

Comment: I think you mean betas. Also you must be 18+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Snapshots](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snapshot) are only available for the Java Edition of Minecraft.

> "*A Snapshot is a testing version of Minecraft, periodically released by Mojang AB. These versions of the game, with "unrefined" features, are available for players to try out. Players may provide feedback and bug-reports to Mojang before the features of the snapshot are implemented into an official update. **Snapshots are available for the Java Edition version of the game**.*"

Comment: What about [Builds](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bedrock_Edition_version_history/Development_versions) for Bedrock? This seems to be the "snapshot" functionality for Bedrock.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/how-get-minecraft-betas) (emphasis mine):

> XBOX ONE / WINDOWS 10
>
> **You will need to own the digital version of the game. For the beta, disc owners are not supported - sorry!**
>
> Joining the Minecraft Beta on Windows 10 or Xbox One:
>
> 1. Go to the Store app on Xbox One or a Windows 10 PC.
> 2. Search for the Xbox Insider Hub app.
> 3. Download and install Xbox Insider Hub.
> 4. Launch the Xbox Insider Hub.
> 5. Navigate to Insider content > Minecraft Beta.
> 6. Select Join.
> 7. Have fun and find bugs!

Comment: But there is no mention of the OP having a disc version of Minecraft.

Comment: @Joachim correct; but this answer covers both bases. If you are using the disc to play Minecraft, you cannot access the snapshots.